# Make SQL ignore a specific search value if clicked in a dropdown?

Tags: php, sql, forms

I am creating a multi-form search box that searches a Meat packaging database. The search works only if users are specific, I want them to be able to search the database without having to choose a specific option from the dropdown box, limiting the number of searches.

Is it possible to add an option into the dropdown boxes such as "Any" and have the SQL query ignore it if the user chooses it? So then it will only search for results that match those of the ones within the text forms?

Here is the HTML and PHP:

```
 <body>

  <form action="form3.php" method="post"> 
    <label for ="description">Description:</label>
    <input type="text" name="descrip" /><br />

    <label for ="trayheight">Trayheight:</label>
    <input type="text" name="height" /> <br /> 

    <label for ="traywidth">Traywidth:</label>
    <input type="text" name="width" /> <br />

    <label for ="traydepth">Traydepth:</label>
    <input type="text" name="depth" /> <br />

         <label for="trayrange">Trayrange: </label>
                <select name="trayrange">
                    <option value="Other">Any</option>

                    <option value="BBQ">BBQ</option>

                    <option value="Dessert">Dessert</option>

                    <option value="Display">Display</option>

                    <option value="Meat">Meat</option>  

                    <option value="Microwave">Microwave</option>

                    <option value="Party">Party</option>

                    <option value="Salad/Wet Pasta">Salad/Wet Pasta</option>

                    <option value="Snacks">Snacks</option>

                    <option value="Standard">Standard</option>

                </select>

        <label for ="traytype">Traytype: </label> 
            <select name="traytype">
                    <option value="Other">Any</option>

            <option value="Open">Open</option>

            <option value="Cavitised">Cavitised</option>

                    <option value="Lid">Lid</option>

                    <option value="Tray">Tray</option>

                    <option value="Coallition">Coallition</option>

                    <option value="Bowl">Bowl</option>

                    <option value="Hinge pack">Open</option>

                    <option value="Pot">Pot</option>

                    <option value="Base & Lid">Base and Lid</option>

                    <option value="Rectangular">Rectangular</option>

                    <option value="Specalist">Specialist</option>
                </select><br />

        <label for="trayshape">Trayshape: </label>
            <select name="trayshape">
                    <option value="Other">Any</option>

            <option value="Rectangular">Rectangular</option>

                <option value="Oval">Oval</option>

                <option value="Square">Square</option>

                    <option value="Insert">Insert</option>

                    <option value="Round">Round</option>

                    <option value="Open">Open</option>
        </select><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form> 

        </body>
```

(Maybe making it so the Any option just makes the code ignore the dropboxes for the search)

PHP:

```
      <body>

    <?php
         $con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
         mysql_select_db ("delyn_db", $con);

    if (!$con)
        { 
        die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
        }

            $descrip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descrip']); 
            $height = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['height']);
            $width = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['width']);
            $depth = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['depth']);

            $varRange = $_POST['trayrange'];
            $varType = $_POST['traytype'];
            $varShape = $_POST['trayshape'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM delyn WHERE description LIKE '%".$descrip."%' AND trayheight
                    LIKE '%".$height."%'AND traywidth LIKE '%".$width."%' AND traydepth LIKE
                    '%".$depth."%' AND trayrange LIKE '%".$varRange."%' AND 
                    traytype LIKE '%".$varType."%' AND trayshape LIKE '%".$varShape."%' ";


    $r_query = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query))
            { 
            echo '<br /> Tool Code:   '.$row['toolcode'];
            echo '<br /> Description: '.$row['description']; 
            echo '<br /> Tray range:  '.$row['trayrange']; 
            echo '<br /> Tray type:   '.$row['traytype'];
                echo '<br /> Tray size:   '.$row['traysize']; 
            echo '<br /> Tray shape:  '.$row['trayshape'] . '<br />' . 
                            '<br />'; ;  
                    }

        if (mysql_num_rows($r_query) <= 0){
            echo 'No results match your search, please try again';
               }
        ?>
      </body>
```

If anyone could help that would be great, thanks in advance :)

Comment: General guidance - don't ask SQL to ignore, simply don't tell SQL to do anything with it.  You are the writer of the code: detect the value you want to ignore, and ignore it

Comment: So with the ANY value from the dropbox, how would you get the search function to ignore it? Code within the $sql= "SELECT * ... etc or an IF loop within the php page? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your $sql differently:

```
$varRange="";
if ($_POST['trayrange'] != "*") {
$varRange="and trayrange like %".$_POST['trayrange']."%";
}
```

then concatenate

```
$sql="select"...$varRange...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your assumption that if the "Any" options is used it would be better to not include the filter in the query (as you are generating the query).

An other option is to use a multi-select control and if the length of the selection is zero, then not too generate the filter

A word of caution, the extensive use of the LIKE keyword will lead to performance issues if the table the query is executed on grows.

Comment: Thanks Jacques, what would you suggest instead of LIKE then? I haven't really used much else than LIKE.

Comment: The change away from like would envolve a look into the structure of your database, the simplest solution would to use lookup tables and bind the keys in your dropdown, with the value attribute. Also when it comes to column types it is advisable to use a number type if representing a number

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional parameters as in the following.  You would set the value of a selection of "All" to asterisk or similar and then code your SQL as follows:

```
"SELECT * FROM delyn 
WHERE description LIKE '%".$descrip."%' 
AND ((.$height.   = '*') OR (trayheight LIKE '%".$height."%'))
AND ((.$width.    = '*') OR (traywidth LIKE '%".$width."%')) 
AND ((.$depth.    = '*') OR (traydepth LIKE %".$depth."%')) 
AND ((.$varRange. = '*') OR (trayrange LIKE '%".$varRange."%')) 
AND ((.$varType.  = '*') OR (traytype LIKE '%".$varType."%')) 
AND ((.$varShape. = '*') OR (trayshape LIKE '%".$varShape."%'))";
```

This example assumes that the first selection - description requires a value.  The user could leave the rest of the selections set to "All".

Comment: This just seems to bring round the errors : _mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean_ :(

Comment: Sorry - I'm not a PHP progrmmer. The basic idea is to first compare the dropdown value to the default value of '*'. If it is true, this line is skipped. If it is not true, then you fall to the OR condition and compare on the value selected in the drop down. This is how I pass results back from multiple selection screens in .Net to SQL procedures.

Comment: As an example I have drop down selections for customer code and warehouse on a screen. The default selection is "ALL" which has a value of '%' The variables with the @ are the parameters which are passed back to the SQL procedure. The where clause is as follows: WHERE ((@CustCode = '%') OR (dbo.watdoc.cust_code = @CustCode)) AND ((@WhseCode = '%') OR (dbo.watdoc.whse_code = @WhseCode))